# Parsing a string to date gives 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Tags: java, parsing

```
  String dateimput=request.getParameter("datepicker");
System.out.printl("datepicker:" +dateimput);   
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    Date dt = null;
    try
    {
        dt = df.parse(dateimput);
        System.out.println("date imput is:" +dt);

    } catch (ParseException e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();

  }
```

*datepicker:04/29/2010  (value I currently selected from datepicker).
*the field in database is typed date.
1-date imput is:Thu Apr 29 00:00:00 CEST 2010
and in database level it is inserted like that 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Comment: This question is a mess. Please make it more intelligible.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the parsed date is printed correctly. Thus the problem must lie elsewhere - in code you don't actually show. How do you expect any meaningful help then?

Comment: What type of Database? Do you pass the correct format? i.e. MySQL Expects Dates (Datetimes) as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss and MM/DD/YYYY might cause this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to put a date into the database ? Are you trying to read a date field from a database ? Which Database ? Can we see the code that does the insert,query ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code will work fine.

04/29/2010 will give you a date object with the correct time/date set.

You said the problem is during the Database insert, so you should tell us the used database and post the code you are using for the insert.

Comment: I use MYSQL DataBase
So this is my query:
String query = "Insert into dailytimesheet(trackingDate,activity,projectCode) values ("+df.format(dt)+", \""+activity+",\""+projet+"\")";

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to echox's answer.  It looks like your problem might be not putting quotes around your date value in your insert statement.